# Predicate with forall quantifier in haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, forall, multiparameter

I want to write the function which accepts values of types, which has instances of multiparameter type class together with *every* type. Something like this (signature of `test` function is illegal):

```
class Test a b

test :: forall a. (forall b. Test a b) => a -> a
```

Is there a way to express such restriction?

Comment: no, there is not. But perhaps you can workaround it; can you give us a small example of what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps you can do with just a single-parameter type class that has methods that universally quantify over what is now the second parameter of your class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, there may be a better solution.

But what you're asking is also possible, using the [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, ConstraintKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Data.Constraint.Forall

class Test a b

test :: Forall (Test a) => a -> a
test = undefined
```